# C Program to Check max Palindrome Number for 3 digits

Tags: c

1. Can anyone please help me to find why this line (please see code) not executing?
2. I'm trying to find max Palindrome Number for 3 digits.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int n, reverse=0, rem,temp,  max_palindrom = -1;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
    {

        for (j = 100; j <= 999; j++)
        {
            n = 1*j;

            temp=n;
            while(temp!=0)
            {
                rem=temp%10;
                reverse=reverse*10+rem;
                temp/=10;
            }

            if(reverse==n)
            {

                printf("DDDDD");   //  < === not executing 

            }

        }
    }

    printf("%d ", max_palindrom);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't printf("DDDDD") executing?  Essentially because the condition 'reverse==n' never becomes true.  How isn't it true?  Insert printf() statements above the 'if (reverse==n)' condition and check the values of reverse and n.  This is how you debug.

Comment: Yeah, I'm downvoting this for, essentially, posting on SO before making any debugging effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not resetting `reverse` back to zero when trying a new number. So digits are being added to it continuously over the course of the whole program, never making it equal to a palindrome.

Try re-initializing it inside the second loop like this:

```
for (j = 100; j <= 999; j++)
{
    reverse = 0;
    ...
```

There are other problems with your code as well, but you'll find those eventually.

Answer (score 0):

As junjanes said you need to reset the reverse variable.  And why you are using two `for loop` as one is sufficient.

For your reference see this modified one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n, reverse=0, rem,temp,  max_palindrom = -1;
int i, j; 

for (j = 100; j <= 999; j++)
{
   n=j;
  temp=n;
  while(temp!=0)
  {
     rem=temp%10;
     reverse=reverse*10+rem;
     temp/=10;
  }
  if(reverse==n)
  {

     printf("DDDDD");   //  < === not executing 

   printf("%d\n", reverse);
  }
  if(max_palindrom<reverse)
  {
     max_palindrom=reverse;
  }
  reverse=0;
  }

   printf("%d ", max_palindrom);
  return 0;
 }
```